# Can you access SharePoint Offline and then Auto Sync when Connected?

Tags: mobile, workspace, offline

I am looking for a way for our users to be able to access SharePoint offline e.g. to view or make changes to documents, complete custom lists etc. and then auto sync when they have connection again.

I can't see a way to do this without using SharePoint Workspace, which I understand has been discontinued? Any ideas? Also, eventually I would like for users to have the ability to do this on mobile phones, so is offline connectivity to SharePoint also possible on mobile technology?

I am using SharePoint Standard 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Server 2013, if a client workstation has Office 2013 installed, users can synchronize files that are stored in document libraries with their client workstations, and vice versa.

> One thing keep in mind SYNC is Supported with Office 2013 only.
>   You can make any Document Library SYNC to your Local Including the SkyDrive PRO Library. Once the Library is SYNCed users can Open, Edit and Add Files and Folders to the SYNCed Library Folder that gets created on your Local. These additions can be Synced back to the Library either Everytime when you connect to SharePoint or On-Demand with “Sync now”.

Read more here: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/12/how-to-work-with-documents-offline-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169080(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, our users will not have access to MS One Drive. Is there another way that you can access SharePoint files and lists offline which then auto sync back to SharePoint when a connection has been established? I am now using SharePoint Enterprise version. Thanks in advance.